# Bounty expired перевод

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, статус-отложено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

В уведомлении о истечении срока награды отсутствует перевод.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перевод [есть](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263181), но он почему-то не применяется.

Comment: @VladD чтобы перейти по вашей ссылке нужна одобренная учетная запись. Какой перевод там?

Comment: @Oceinic: Оригинал: «Your bounty on question "$questionTitle$" has expired.», перевод: «Срок действия вашего вознаграждения за вопрос «$questionTitle$» истек.»

Comment: @Oceinic: Это _не_ тот перевод, который вы предлагаете, но он есть в базе, и должен бы отображаться.

Comment: @VladD: оставил тревогу для Николаса по поводу бага.

Comment: Возникла идея: а может быть вы с другого сайта это уведомление читали? Если так, то строки и должны были остаться непереведенными.

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил контекст. Я в дороге, с мобильного телефона скрин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все необходимые строки об истечении срока конкурса [уже переведены](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263181?q=Your%20bounty%20on%20question%20expire). Здесь дело в том, что локализованные строки не берутся из базы. Проблема на стороне разрабочтиков Stack Overflow.

Поставил соответствующие метки, будем ждать результата.

Текущие переводы:

> Срок действия вашего вознаграждения за вопрос «$questionTitle$» истек.
>
> Ваш конкурс к вопросу «$questionTitle$» заканчивается в течение суток.
>
> Ваш конкурс к вопросу «$questionTitle$» заканчивается в течение трёх суток.
>
> Срок действия вашего вознаграждения за вопрос «$questionTitle$» истек — премируемый ответ выбран автоматически.